# How to increase the speed of this transform.translate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the 2d sprite moving automatically, and was just wondering how to increase the speed of this:

```
transform.Translate(0.10F, -0.03F, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Have tried setting a speed variable and then doing:

```
transform.Translate(0.1f,-0.05f,speed*Time.deltaTime);
```

But this ends up making the background in the game window disappear (because the player is moving off the 2d background via the z axis), whilst in the scene window the player is moving down the map but at the same speed

Comment: whose transform component is that?

Comment: The sprite that i'm trying to move

Comment: I don't know what the parameters of that method are, but on your top one, you're always passing in 0. I'm thinking that your `Time.deltaTime` is such a ridiculously small number (probably well under .1) that anything you're multiplying it by has no effect.

Comment: It is transform.Translate(x, y, z) so the speed*TimedeltaTime is just replacing the z axis direction, and since it is 2d it means the player just goes off the map. Not sure how to change this to speed

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2D, you don't want sprites moving in z axis (It can be useful for draw order only).
Players should be increasing the speed in x or y axis. So in your code, you could do something like this.

```
transform.Translate(xSpeed, ySpeed, 0);
```

If you want to draw something behind this sprite, just supply a value less than z-value of this.
I am assuming that you are calling this in your Update method. Here `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` are floats. Negative values will move the object in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `speed` to `Translate` by multiplying it by the translate vector, `newPosition` in this example:

```
void Update () {
    float speed = 3f;
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3 (.1f, -.05f, 0f);
    transform.Translate (newPosition * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```